# Implementing generic interfaces and overriding methods

Tags: java

I am trying to work with generics and have two questions.

1. Since I made my interface `public interface testInterface<K,V>`, this means that if I implement my interface, "TestInterface", and define the types as < Interger,String> `public class UsingGenerics implements TestInterface<Integer, String>`, respectively. Then when I define the types in the method I am overriding I could use < Interger,String> or Super classes of those correct? So I could do `public void loop(BiConsumer<Integer, String> action)` or `public void loop(BiConsumer<Object, String> action)`, right? Just trying to make sure I understand what `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action` exactly means I can do when I override it
2. I am getting this error

   > have the same erasure, but neither override

   and I cant figure out why.

This is the interface

```
import java.util.function.*;
public interface test<K,V> {

    public void loop(BiConsumer<? super K,? super V> action);

}
```

This is the class

```
public class UsingGenerics implements TestInterface<Integer, String> {

    @Override
    public void loop(BiConsumer<Object, String> action)
    {
        //Something here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I'll assume that test is actually TestInterface. When you compile, you get the following error: "Error:(5, 8) java: UsingGenerics is not abstract and does not override abstract method loop(java.util.function.BiConsumer<? super java.lang.Integer,? super java.lang.String>) in TestInterface". What do you conclude about what the signature of the method should be? It's right there, in the error message.

Comment: BTW, you could also just remove the method, and ask your IDE to add all the missing methods for you.

Comment: Is the interface `test`, or `TestInterface`? Those aren't interchangeable...